# Auto complete stopped working in Spyder

Tags: python3, spyder

Since yesterday that I updated the 'Pygments' installation, the auto complete has stopped working. For more details regarding this update, please see the link below.

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4885-1

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Thanks

Pavlos